# Where do I get Public Key to validate GitHub's access token?

Tags: github, oauth, access-token, public-key

Referring to the following link:

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps

On "**Your app accesses the API with the user's access token**". Where can I get the GitHub's public key to validate the access token.

I know there's an API to validate the access token. But for another reason, I need a public key to validate the access token.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub access tokens are typically not asymmetric, so there is no public key to validate them.  (There are some cases in which GitHub uses JWTs, or at least has, but that is not the typical case.)

New-format GitHub tokens contain a prefix, a random portion generated with a CSPRNG, and then a CRC at the end.  This is documented [on GitHub's blog](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/).  The token is therefore the secret itself and does not contain any actual payload other than the random component.